# Error de sintaxis, "ParseError: bad input on line 9"

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo Python y tengo este ejercicio:

> 4.6 Write a program to prompt the user for hours and rate per hour using input to compute gross pay. Award time-and-a-half for the hourly rate for all hours worked above 40 hours. Put the logic to do the computation of time-and-a-half in a function called computepay() and use the function to do the computation. The function should return a value. Use 45 hours and a rate of 10.50 per hour to test the program (the pay should be 498.75). You should use input to read a string and float() to convert the string to a number. Do not worry about error checking the user input unless you want to - you can assume the user types numbers properly. Do not name your variable sum or use the sum() function.

Mi respuesta es la siguiente:

```
def compute_pay(hours):       
    if hours <= 40:
       pay = pay * hours
       return pay

hours = float(raw_input("Enter Hours:"))   
pay = float(raw_input("Enter Rate:")) 

print compute_pay(hours)
```

Pero cuando al correrlo, me dice:

> "ParseError: bad input on line 9"

Comment: Nay ¿Es ese todo tu código? ¿Cúales son las líneas ocho y nueve en tu script? El código que muestras solo tiene un error (independientemente de la lógica), `pay` no está definido en lo que muestras pero no es ese el error por el que consultas. Por otro lado ¿usas Python 2 o Python 3? Tenias añadida la etiqueta Python-3.x pero ese código es para Python 2....

Comment: El problema es esto: `def compute_pay(hours)`, te falta definir el parámetro `pay`, o sea: `def compute_pay(hours, pay)`